# configure command not found cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin

This question has been asked many time but I am not able to resolve the problem from them so I am asking

I had installed Cygwin a few days ago.I tried using `./configure` command but it says

> -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

I tried using

```
where configure
```

but I got the output

> INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

then I tried `grep configure`and I got this output

```
/etc/bash_completion.d/configure
/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/share/libtool/libltdl/configure
/usr/share/ELFIO/configure
/usr/share/libtool/libltdl/configure
```

I tried to export the path and then run the `./configure` but it also didn't worked.

I find no executable file named as `configure` in my cygwin `bin` directory.

Does it mean that I have to add `configure` file manually?How can I correct it?

NOTE :- **I had also tried `sh configure` but it also didn't worked**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a software project is set up to be built using [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/), that tool generates a script canonically called `configure`. It queries the system for various parameters that are subsequently used in the build, and is *specific to the software package to be built*. Different software projects have different `configure` scripts. They are all called `configure`, but their contents are not the same.

So, to actually build such a software project once that script was set up (usually done by the maintainers when packaging the source tarball for distribution), you call:

```
tar xzf <tarball>.gz   # or xjf <tarball>.bz2 or whatever
cd <sourcedir>         # the one you just untarred
./configure
make
make install
```

Note the prefix `./`, which means "located *in this directory*" (i.e. the top directory of that project's source tree).

Actually, the *better* procedure is the so-called "out-of-tree build", when you set up a *different* directory for the binaries to be built in, so the source tree remains unmodified:

```
tar xzf <tarball>.gz     # or xjf <tarball>.bz2 or whatever
mkdir builddir
cd builddir
../<sourcedir>/configure
make
make install
```

So, there is *supposed* to be no `configure` executable in your `PATH`, you are supposed to call the script of that name from the source tree you are trying to build from.

Answer (score 7):

If I correctly understood...

Configure is not an application that should be installed on your system, but script that should be delivered with source code to prepare for `make` command. File named `configure` should be in the main directory of source code.

Comment: ok my bad..so can i update the script of configure to the latest version because it says `this script last modified 2003-01-05 has failed to recognize your operating system`??

Answer (score 6):

I understand that this is an old question. However many might find this solution helpful.

Normally we use the make command to compile a downloaded source in cygwin. In many cases it contains a autogen.sh file. Running that file with

```
bash autogen.sh
```

will in many case solve the problem. At least it solved my issue and i could then use the make command

Comment: This is the correct answer. (Yes, you need to have installed `autoconf`.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed 'autoconf' yet?  You may have to run the cygwin installation exe again (ie setup-x86_64.exe) and select this option to install.

You may also need 'automake' as well (ie if you have to deal with a Makefile.am)

[Click here to see Image of how to install autoconf and automake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IQp6.jpg)

NOTE - just realized, you may need to install 'libtool' as well